# Text mining on Facebook public page

Tags: facebook, r, text-mining

I'm a graduate student. I would like to do a text mining on Facebook public pages for my research. Anybody knows how to export all the wall comments posted on a particular public page into csv or html/xml format? In addition, I found the 'R' coding to mining the twitter. Can I do the same on Facebook public page? If anyone has done so and could share the coding with me, I'll appreciate it.
Thanks.

Comment: Remember to ask for permission before scrapping any data
https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php

Answer (score 0):

There does seem to have been some work done using Python to scrape facebook pages, this might be worth following up:
http://heuristically.wordpress.com/2011/04/08/text-data-mining-twitter-r/#comment-103